# Facebook In-App Browser on iPhone & Android doesn't submit the form on website

Tags: android, ios, forms, facebook, submission

I have a newsletter signup on our site that just requires and email address to submit. The form submission is successful on all desktop browsers and mobile browsers. The problem is that the form errors when someone views the site from the Facebook apps in-app browser. The user will get an invalid email address error. We were originally using MailChimp, the error said something slightly different with them, but moved to Campaign Monitor. The url to the site is https://consciousink.com. I have contacted both Campaign Monitor and Facebook. Campaign Monitor said it was a Facebook issue. Facebook has emailed me every so often stating that their developers are working on it. But they give no details. Pretty sure my form is not a priority. Any help or suggestions to fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Facebook can't use forms with `target="_blank"`. I think that's because in-app browser doesn't have tabs.